# ruby 2.0.0 bundle fails with 'key: value' on Gemfile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, key-value, gemfile

I'm trying to update my gems using a Gemfile but always fails in the same line:

Gemfile:

```
group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Command:

```
$ bundle update
```

I'm always getting this error:

> Gemfile syntax error:
>   /Users/GrzegorzFeathers/Documents/Edx/SaaS/rottenpotatoes/Gemfile:32: syntax
>   error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
>   gem 'sdoc', require: false

When I change that line syntax to this, the problem was solved:

```
    gem 'sdoc', :require => false
```

But why can't I use the other one?, I checked my ruby version in two different ways and both says that I'm using ruby 2.0.0 so I should be able to use key: value syntax

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

And:

```
$ rails console
2.0.0-p247 :001 > RUBY_VERSION
 => "2.0.0"
```

Any idea of what's happening?

EDIT:
To solve the problem I've just reinstalled the bundler gem, and then everything worked as expected :)

```
$ gem install bundler
```

Comment: Maybe bundler is using a different version for some reason? As another check, try putting `puts RUBY_VERSION` at the top of your Gemfile and see what it prints when you run `bundle install`

Comment: @SeanMackesey I added the line to the Gemfile but it doesn't print anything, still getting the same error

Comment: It was very weird, I just needed to reinstall bundler gem and then it worked fine, thanks @SeanMackesey