# ruby on rails tutorial - gemfile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just started doing the "Ruby on Rails Tutorial", from Michael Hartl. I've created a new project.My Gemfile from given below:

```
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0
```

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

After that I tried to execute in terminal 
`$ bundle install --without production`
Then I got following error

```
    nikhil@ubuntu:~/rails_projects/demo_app$ bundle install --without production
/home/nikhil/rails_projects/demo_app/Gemfile:29:in `evaluate': compile error (SyntaxError)
/home/nikhil/rails_projects/demo_app/Gemfile:23: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
                                ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:13
```

I am a fresher just trying to study RoR please help me to fix this error
Thanks

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529891/ruby-2-0-0-bundle-fails-with-key-value-on-gemfile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574405/error-in-your-gemfile-and-bundler-cannot-continue

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments, the issue is almost certainly caused by the following line in your Gemfile:

```
#Gemfile
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

According to the answers on the other questions, you will most likely be able to fix the issue by using the following syntax:

```
#Gemfile
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', :require => false
end
```

---

**Bundler**

Thanks to `@mandeep` in the comments, you'll also want to look at updating your version of [`bundler`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler)

To do this, you just have to `cd` into the working directory for your Rails application, and then run:

```
gem update bundler
```

This will install the latest version of the `bundler` gem in your application, which should also go towards resolving the error you're seeing too

Comment: Rails version is '4.0.8' so i don't think it would be ruby <= 1.8.x so new hash should not give error :)

Comment: Yeah but strangely in more cases or not it was resolved by updating bundler

Comment: Why don't you write an answer about that then? The guy is obviously new, so he needs as many ideas & things to try as possible. If my answer isn't correct, it leaves room for you to write a more apt one!

Comment: I'm not saying that it isn't correct or anything. Just saying you should add the other part of it too :)

Comment: lol okay I'll add the other part - but you may want to add an answer consider I just took the ideas from the resources you provided. Bottom line is if the guy is new, he needs as many points of reference as possible; hence why I'd recommend you write an answer too

Comment: Hey Rich.. Need your help again @Mandeep is trying to point out but if you have any idea then please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687970/in-production-mode-on-heroku-devises-conforming-mail-cant-send?noredirect=1